# Why is EUR/CAD market open now?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange

As far as I know the Euro follows London times (closed right now), and CAD session is almost the same as USD session (closed right now as well) so why is EUR/CAD market open and trading right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreign exchange market trades 24/5 in all currency pairs - Sunday evening to Friday evening.

When you mention opening times for a particular currency, you are probably thinking of stock markets or interest rate markets in that currency.

Comment: What is "evening" in this (worldwide) context? UTC?

Comment: I was deliberately a bit vague because I'm not sure of the exact times and how they change with DST - I found conflicting references. It's roughly 5pm Eastern Time.

Comment: I've since become acquainted with this. Turns out that the forex market itself has a opening and closing time and that's different from regional "sessions" like European, American and Asian. From Investopedia: _The forex market is open 24 hours a day in different parts of the world, **from 5 p.m. EST on Sunday until 4 p.m. EST on Friday.**_

Comment: @AspiringDev whereas Wikipedia (no doubt a bit unreliable) says 10pm to 10pm UTC and I can't quickly find a definitive answer about how daylight davings affects it.

Comment: From empirical evidence I know it opens 5 p.m. EST on Sunday.

Comment: @AspiringDev even in summer? (when EST will be one hour off from the actual time in New York)

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica not sure if they follow DST actually.